# How to perform arithmetic within siunitx?

Tags: siunitx, calculations

I often put comments in my documents to remind me where a number comes from:

```
\SI{39.68}{\milli\metre} deep % 0.31 * 128
```

I'd like LaTeX to calculate the product by itself. I wrote a function to do that with `fp`, and it works (although I'd like a shorter one). But it doesn't work within `\SI`:

```
\newcommand{\mult}[2]{%
    \FPmul{\tempSum}{#1}{#2}%
    \FPround\roundedSum\tempSum2%
    \roundedSum%
}

\mult{0.31}{128} mm deep % works

\SI{\mult{0.31}{128}}{\milli\metre} deep % does not work
```

How to solve this?

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! siunitx error: "invalid-number"
! 
! Invalid numerical input '\edef {\FP@mul \tempSum 0.31..\relax 128..\relax
! }\edef {\FP@round \roundedSum ..\relax }{2}'.
! 
! See the siunitx documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

Comment: Use `\SI[parse-numbers=false]`. Maybe you are also interested in a L3 multiplication: `\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \mult {  m m  }
 {
  \fp_eval:n { round( #1 * #2  ,2 ) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`siunitx` parses numerical inputs with some options. However the input of the number isn't expanded before manipulating. To use tokens inside the first mandatory argument you can use the option `parse-numbers=false`.

If you define an expandable version of `\mult` you can use it as a valid input of `\SI`. In the example below this is done by `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` provided by `xparse`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xparse} 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \mult {  m m  }
 {
  \fp_eval:n { round( #1 * #2  ,2 ) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\mult{0.31}{128}

\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\mult{0.31}{128}}{\milli\metre} deep

\SI{\mult{0.31}{128}}{\milli\metre} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Using the module `l3fp` you can define arithmetic functions very easy. In the example above I used your definition with two mandatory arguments. However you can also use:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \Func { O{2} m   }
 {
  \fp_eval:n { round( #2   , #1 ) }
 }
```

Now `\Func` has two arguments the first one is optional and specifies the rounding. The second is passed to `fp_eval`:

```
\Func{0.38*4}
```

Comment: Thanks! I suppose `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `l3fp` only work with LaTeX 3?

Comment: @TimN: This is LaTeX3. The package `siunitx` is written with the core language of L3 -- `expl3`.

Comment: Isn't it a bit weird to assume that I'm using LaTeX3, given that it hasn't been released yet?

Comment: @TimN: The used moduls are all stable. You can find a lot of packages using LateX3. Eg.: `siunitx`, `fnpct`, `xpatch`, ...

Comment: @TimN: Please see edit.

Comment: @TimN 'LaTeX3' at present refers to the bits that are finished as much as the bigger 'a new format' idea. The code layer is pretty solid, and it's used by `siunitx`, so it's available to use without worrying.