# How can I show a leading + sign in siunitx S column?

Tags: tables, formatting, siunitx

I'm using `siunitx`'s `S` columntype to align numbers in a table. The numbers are percentage values which should all have a preceding sign (some - and some +).

The numbers with a "-" are shown with a sign, the "+" sign vanishes as `siunitx` processes the numbers.

How can I keep the sign of the numbers including the "+" sign?

Comment: `\sisetup{retain-explicit-plus}` (as detailed in the manual)

Comment: that doesn't work in table environment as it seems... I found another way to do that!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pluses are retained is `retain-explicit-plus` is set

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[retain-explicit-plus]}
  +1.23 \\
  -4.56 \\
   7.89 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{doument}
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, seems that I've found a solution:

I tried `retain-explicit-plus` as an option for `\num` but that doesn't do any good in tables.

What I did is fairly similar [to this question:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194717/num-with-parameters-in-siunitx-table)

Just omit the "+" sign for numbers that are positive (which gives them the "+" sign stated in `S[explicit-sign=+]`) and write a minus sign for negative numbers. This makes it work for mixed sign columns!

Comment: okay, Joseph Wright's solution does also work...