# Addition/Multiplication of quantities with uncertainties in siunitx

Tags: siunitx, expl3

Related with [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114641/how-to-perform-arithmetic-within-siunitx), I would like to perform arithmetic operations of siunitx numbers that have uncertainties. For example multiply two numbers using `\mult{0.2(1)e2}{2(1)e2}` should give `0.4(3)e4` calculating the error in quadrature. Ignoring the uncertainties and giving `0.4e4` is also fine. The problem is that the input numbers contain uncertainties because they are given in a series of macros using the parenthesis form for the errors, and they are not handled correctly by the `expl3` module.

Edit: This is a MWE although it does not work at the moment. If a round off parameter of `2` is supplied to the function it should give `5.45`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{expl3}

\newcommand{\a}{6.0(1)e2}
\newcommand{\b}{1.1(1)e2}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \Func {m m m}
{
  \fp_eval:n { round( #1/#2, #3 ) }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Func{\a}{\b}{2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you supply us with your actual use-case as input in the form of a minimal example? We need to know whether you manually type `0.2(1)`, or whether you get that from a file, or perhaps it's part of a n (expandable) macro. Again, a minimal example (that starts with `\documentclass{article}` and ends with `\end{document}`).

Comment: I have added a minimal example

Answer (score 2):

The following code will at least achieve one of your goals: calculating the result and ignoring the uncertainty (the example will output `5.45`).

If you would like to calculate the uncertainties have a look at `\regex_extract_...` in `interface3.pdf` which allows you to make a match out of the regex below and then use the numbers given to calculate the error as you like.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{expl3}

\newcommand{\one}{6.0(1)e2}
\newcommand{\two}{1.1(1)e2}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \Func {m m m}
{
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { \(\d\) } { } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { #2 }
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { \(\d\) } { } \l_tmpb_tl
    \fp_eval:n { round( \l_tmpa_tl / \l_tmpb_tl, #3 ) }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Func{\one}{\two}{2}

\end{document}
```